# Register Visual-Basic 6 Component Manually?

Tags: windows-7, components

I made VB6 Applications and used some components like Winsock, Webbrowser and etc in my program.
Now when i run my application on any other computers, it says :

> Component 'MSWINSCK.OCX' or one of its dependencies not correctly
>   registered: a file is missing or invalid.

**The Ways i tried:** 
I tried to copy mswinsck.ocx to System32 folder and try to open the application again, but this error comes again !

So i think i can register this component using :

> Regsvr32 mswinsck.ocx

but i couldn't succeeded !

 Also i don't want to use Installer programs. so

**My Question:**

How can i Register a Visual Basic 6 Component Manually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Install the [Visual Basic 6.0 SP6 run-time files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887).
2. If you're on a Win7 64-bit PC then copy the DLLs, OCXs etc. to `%windir%\SysWoW64` and *not* `%windir%\System32` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows) for an explanation).
3. Open an elevated/admin command prompt (search for **cmd** in the Start Menu search box, right-click, **Run as administrator**) and try to register the OCX using **regsvr32**.
4. If none of this works you might need to add the VB6 licensing keys to the registry. See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318597) for details.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft Support page [How to register an ActiveX control (.ocx) manually](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146219), use:

```
Regsvr32 /s MSWINSCK.OCX
```

Comment: /s seems to be just for silent mode, so if without it the command failed it shouldn't work with it either.

Comment: I Tried it without /s parameter, because its for Silent-Mode. However Karan said.